# How do I update Grafana dashboard through it's API

Tags: grafana, dashboard, grafana-api

I want to update the grafana dashboard through its API but i have found out 2 problems:

1. i got an 412 HTTP error `{'message': 'A dashboard with the same name in the folder already exists', 'status': 'name-exists'}`
2. when i change the name of the dash board it is getting moved to general folder

i got the json for updating the dashboard by:

1. getting current state of dashboard by downloading it through API
2. changing a few variables (right now i just changed those trying to make it stay in current folder)

```
response_json["meta"]["folderId"] = folder_id
response_json["meta"]["folderUid"] = folder_uid
response_json["meta"]["overwrite"] = True
response_json["dashboard"]["uid"] = dashboard_uid
response_json["dashboard"]["id"] = dashboard_id
```

I'm not changing anything else, i don't know therefore why I'm getting problems with name-exists; ofc it exists i want to update it not create a new one, so its expected that the dashboard exists.

I have tried changing the name of the dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```py
def get_dashboard_by_uid(uid: str):
    # _headers contains Authorization with the bearer
    endpoint = f'{_url}/dashboards/uid/{uid}'
    return requests.get(endpoint, headers=_headers, verify=False).json()

def update_dashboard():
    dashboard = get_dashboard_by_uid('<your-dashboard-uid>')
    endpoint = f'<url>/dashboards/db'
    headers = _headers
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    headers['Host'] = '<your-host>'
    dashboard['dashboard']['title'] = 'Change from API update'
    dashboard['folderId'] = <your-folder-id>
    return requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(dashboard), headers=headers, verify=False).json()
```

From the [API doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/dashboard/):

You have to provide multiple fields in the JSON, the first one is the dashboard json model and the rest is the folder, a message for the commit version history and the overwrite property.

> {
> "dashboard": {
> json_dashboard_model
> },
> "folderId": 0,
> "folderUid": "l3KqBxCMz",
> "message": "Made changes to xyz",
> "overwrite": false
> }

With this line in the code: `dashboard['folderId'] = <your-folder-id>`
you can add the object to the folder in which you want your dashboard.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c88Hb.png)

[after code run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgVYx.png)